# adodb with sql server odbc connection problem

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

> ADODB Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I downloaded the odbc driver for PHP. I pasted that driver in the PHP ext directory, then I get the error. Can anybody help me?

Comment: your question is not clear; you should provide example code.

Answer (score 1):

A few things that I would try,

- Make sure that the extension is included in your php.ini
- Make sure that you've extracted the db driver to the right place c:\windows\drivers in some cases!
- Have you rebooted? As you'll need to reboot your server to load the driver, I assume you have as you get the error :)

As the comment above states, which driver you are using, it's version, and which database you're connecting to would also be handy to know :)

I assume that you're using PHP5 to connect to MSSQL2005. In which case the driver is really dodgy, or was when I last worked with it. It would maintain a connection about 1/3 tries. What web server are you using? As I recall when we were using IIS to serve the PHP+MSSql we had some configuration to do in the IIS setup.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
# config file
$oODBC = new stdClass();
$oODBC->driver = "odbc_mssql";
$oODBC->dns = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=yourdatabhase;";
$oODBC->user = "username";
$oODBC->pass = "password";

# connect
$mDB = $oODBC;
$db =& ADONewConnection($mDB->driver); // ex: odbc_mssql
$db->PConnect($mDB->dns, $mDB->user, $mDB->pass);
```